# Unreachable code detected, how do I fix this with if and else statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, account

I have a problem with getting this right. All i get is unreachable code detected. I can run the program with that warning but it doesn't work correctly. What is it that i don't see?

this is the last part of my code:

```
class Account
    {        
       private double balance = 0;


       public Account()
       {
       }//end construcor

        //Constructor initializes balance with an amount supplied as argument
       public Account(double amount)
        {
            Balance = amount;
        }// end constructor    

       //property to get and set the balance value
        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return balance;
            }
            set
            {
                balance = value;
            }
        }// end property


        public void ShowMessage(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }


        public double Deposit(double depositAmount)
        {

            Balance += depositAmount * 1.05;
            return Balance ;
        }

        public double Withdraw(double WithdrawAmount)
        {
            Balance -= WithdrawAmount;
            return Balance;

            if (WithdrawAmount > this.Balance)
                this.ShowMessage("You do not have enough money!");
            else
                this.Balance -= WithdrawAmount;
            return this.Balance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect your `Withdraw` method to do? You have a `return` in the middle of it. Do you understand what the `return` keyword does?

Comment: It is the Withdraw part that is the problem, wrong use of if and else statements, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: No; you simply need to understand what `return` means and when to use it.  This has nothing to do with `if`.

Comment: The withdraw metod should tell me that if I withdraw more than what  i have, it displays the error message "You do not have enough money!" and if i withdraw without exceeding the amount that i have in the account then it should tell me what I have left. Was is a little bit blurr or did u understand? :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure we understand fine. We are trying to say the problem does not lie with your if statement, but with your early return.

Answer (score 3):

The entire last block of `Withdraw` is unreachable because you `return` in the second line, which returns the argument to the caller and exits the function.

It *looks* like you should just remove the first two lines entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd line `return Balance;` will exit the method there, and so the if/else is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
public double Withdraw(double WithdrawAmount)
    {
        Balance -= WithdrawAmount;
        return Balance;

        if (WithdrawAmount > this.Balance)
            this.ShowMessage("You do not have enough money!");
        else
            this.Balance -= WithdrawAmount;
        return this.Balance;
    }
```

The Second line ends the life of the function.

```
  Balance -= WithdrawAmount;  
  return Balance;
```

that's my solution:

```
The Withdraw logic as I see it: 

 if (Balance < WithdrawAmount)
 {
    ShowMessage("You do not have enough money!");
 }
 else
 {
    Balance -= WithdrawAmount;
 }

 return Balance;
```

If you can't Withdraw, print a message else you withdraw the amount.

at any case, you return the current Balance.